# Is this structure correct in English?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this structure correct in English? "for whom her efforts are thanked and appreciated"

Comment: Probably not, but we'd need to see the full sentence it's embedded in to be sure.

Comment: Even as a clause it doesn't work, because the efforts are appreciated but the person is thanked.